# SwiftUI's contextMenu(forSelectionType:menu:primaryAction:) returns an incorrect amount of rows if the selection is manually modified

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-contextmenu

I'm facing a weird issue with `contextMenu(forSelectionType:menu:primaryAction:)` attached to a `List`. It works fine if you enable edit mode, and start selecting the rows by tapping, but if you have a button that what it does is manually modify the selection, the returned rows when the contextMenu is invoked is incorrect.
Furthermore, if you use the select all button, but actually scroll to the bottom of the list, the returned values is correct, so it seems that unless the cell is rendered, the contextMenu won't return it.
Does anybody know if I'm doing something wrong? Here's a quick example to reproduce the issue:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let rows = (0..<100).map{ "Row: \($0)" }
    @State var selection: Set<String> = []

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(rows, id: \.self) { row in
                Text(row).tag(row)
            }
        }.contextMenu(forSelectionType: String.self) { contextMenuRows in
            Button("Number of rows in the contextMenu: \(contextMenuRows.count)") {}
        }.toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                if selection.isEmpty {
                    Button("Select All") { selection = Set(rows) }
                } else {
                    Button("Deselect All") { selection = [] }
                }
            }

            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to embed the `ContentView` inside a `NavigationView` to be able to see the navigation bar.

Video demo showing the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7As0.jpg

1. Works fine when selecting manually
2. When selecting all only displays the first 9 rows
3. After scrolling, all rows are available to the contextMenu

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between contextMenuRows (the menu parameter) and selection. This can be verified with:

```
Button("Number of rows in the contextMenu: \(contextMenuRows.count) \(selection.count)")
```

The use of selection on menu closure is perhaps what you are looking for.

(It's weird that the "Edit/Select All" menu on the Mac, sets contextMenuRows equal to selection)

Comment: Yes, I ended up using the selection instead of what's returned in the closure. But IMHO the current behavior looks like a bug to me since if you manually scroll the list after tapping select all, the value returned in the closure will match the selection.

Comment: @XaviMoll yes I think it is an Apple bug, I reported to Feedback Assistant. While we can get the full selection for our purposes, the number reported on the badge shown to the user is incorrect. Were you able to find a workaround for that?

Comment: @XaviMoll Also I noticed if your list is long enough scrolling to the bottom won't work still, the badge is still off. I was thinking of programmatically scrolling the list or something, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: @SteveM I never found a solution that kept the badge properly in sync, I've just been using the value in my `@State` property that tracks the `selection` to be able to access everything that's selected. I haven't tried it on iOS 17 yet, maybe they have fixed it.